# Generics ExpressibleByStringLiteral String conversion

Tags: swift, string, generics

I want to create an extension to `String` which takes a type `T` as an input and creates an `Array` of that type `T` with the string seperated into components by a `String` as input:

```
extension String {
    func convertToArrayOfTypesWithSeperator<T: ExpressibleByStringLiteral>(type : T.Type, seperator: String) -> [T] {
        var res : [T] = []
        self.components(separatedBy: seperator).forEach { s in
            // Cast to Type
            // Add to res
        }
        return res
    }
}
```

Now i know that `T` has to conform to `ExpressibleByStringLiteral` which as the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/expressiblebystringliteral) state should have an init:

```
init(stringLiteral value: Self.StringLiteralType)
```

So i try to cast my string component `s` to the type i passed as input using:

```
let t = type.init(stringLiteral: s)
```

But I keep getting errors about it having no initializer using those parameters. What is going wrong here?

Comment: Does this really warrant an extension? `s.components(separatedBy: ", ").map(SomeClass.init)`

Comment: You should use the functional map algorithm, which makes things easier: `yourString.components(separatedBy: separator).map{YourType($0)}`

Comment: But what if you have more specific demands than what I'm currently writing. It is in this case not about the result but the way to achieve it using generics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used it myself but from the looks of it I can't see what guarantees there are that `Self.StringLiteralType` has to equal `String`, hence you can't just pass an instance of `String` to the constructor.

Solution: cast `s` to `T.StringLiteralType`

Comment: Got a bit confused myself while typing this out on mobile. But hopefully fixed now.

Comment: Yes thanks! It works now. Does not work with my end goal (using Int and Float as an function argument T since they have an init(text : String) but is working for string literals.

Comment: Why don't you just define your own protocol and extend all the types you want to work with? No need to depend on `ExpressibleByStringLiteral`.

Comment: Yeah that was the alternative but I thought that it would be redundant since so many literals already have initializers with string. But apparently they don't follow a standard protocol.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately it would have made no difference if their init signatures were identical in this case, which is probably for the best. It would've been weird if Swift encouraged code like `let num: Int = "5"`